# iOS controlling the scroll position of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'v some strings of different size in an array, i added them to `UIScrollView` by using `UILabel`[image: As shown in image]

user can scroll horizontally to see all the names.But i want when user scroll either side he should see next/previous name from list as we do in paging enabled scroll view but here i want only one name(of different size) to be scrolled, not the whole screen.How to achieve this?Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**Edit: -** for better understanding suppose initially 0th, 1st and 2nd strings from my array is visible on scroll view, and when user scroll it should show 1st, 2nd and 3rd strings from my array(and vice versa for scrolling to other side).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by contentoffset.

set contentoffset of scrollview and you can able to do this.

Comment: where should i call this method?In scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: @Blios You can add this in Button click event.. Or even can do it in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method.. Can you try it and check it how it reacts.

Comment: @Blios then add it in Scrolldidscroll method..also you can do it by touchevent method also.